# Does GHCi not apply the default declaration to resolve type ambiguity?

Tags: haskell, types, default, ghci, ambiguity

Being relatively new to Haskell, I'm trying to wrap my head around the following discrepancy (for which there is a good reason, I'm sure).
Perhaps my question simply stems from a misunderstanding of GHCi, but I'll sleep better at night when I can put my doubts to rest.

Here goes. If, after binding a name, `foo`, to some integral expression (simply `1`, here) in a script and compiling that script, I load the latter in GHCi, `:t` tells me that the type of `foo` is `Integer`.

```
$ printf %s\\n "foo=1" > foo.hs
$ ghci
λ> :l foo.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( foo.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
λ>  :t foo
foo :: Integer
```

As I understand it, the ambiguity in the type of `foo` is resolved thanks to some [*default declaration*](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4), which, I presume, is specified somewhere in `Prelude`:

```
default (Integer, Double)
```

So far, so good. However, when I carry out a seemingly equivalent `let` binding directly inside GHCi, `:t` tells me that the latter still treats `foo` as a polymorphic numeric constant, *not* as an `Integer`:

```hs
$ ghci
λ> let foo=1
λ> :t foo
foo :: Num a => a
```

How can this discrepancy be explained? What is the rationale behind it? Does GHCi not apply the [*default declaration*](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4) to resolve type ambiguity? And if it does, in what situations does it do it?

(For information, I'm using GHC 7.8.3.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does ghci not apply the default declaration to resolve type ambiguity?

In GHC 7.8 or greater the [Monomorphism Restriction](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-930004.5.5) is indeed off inside the GHCi shell, so declarations at the interactive shell will not apply the Num defaulting rules to top level expressions not under a lambda binder ( per the monomorphism restriction ). The monomorphism restriction will still apply to external modules that are loaded.

You can toggle this with `:set -XMonomorphismRestriction`.

Comment: Thanks. I've taken the liberty to add a link to the relevant section  of the Haskell 2010 report, which I found thanks to your answer.

Comment: Defaulting rules still apply in some situations (I couldn't say exactly which). For example, `show 1` will default the `1` to `Integer`. The monomorphism restriction relaxation just avoids applying the defaults unnecessarily.

Comment: @dfeuer Rearranged the phrasing, hopefully it's a bit clearer.